# docker replacing container ip with gateway ip

Tags: docker

I have a request going from container A to container B.

container A ip is : 172.24.0.35

container B ip is : 172.24.0.33

Inspecting the request on container B the sender ip is 172.24.0.1.
Why is the sender ip originating from 172.24.0.1 and not the container A ip of 172.24.0.35

I have not done any changes to the networking.

This is my compose file for container A.

```
asterisk:
  extends:
    file: common.yml
    service: asterisk
  depends_on:
    - base
  ports:
    - "5038:5038"
    - "5060:5060/tcp"
    - "5060:5060/udp"
    - "16380-16420:16380-16420/udp"
  volumes_from:
    - base
  volumes:
    - /var/log/asterisk/
    - /dev/shm/
    - /dev/dahdi:/dev/dahdi
    - ./etc/conf/asterisk:/etc/asterisk/:ro
  networks:
    default:
      aliases:
        - asterisk
```

container B

```
asterisk-agent:
  extends:
    file: common.yml
    service: asterisk-agent
  depends_on:
    - base
  volumes_from:
    - base
  volumes:
    - /var/log/asterisk/
    - /dev/shm/
    - /dev/dahdi:/dev/dahdi
    - ./etc/conf/asterisk/agent/:/etc/asterisk/:ro
  networks:
    default:
      aliases:
        - asterisk-agent
```

Comment: Are u using any docker network to connect the containers?

Comment: Using the default setup.  request from external ip -> host

Comment: can you provide compose file for container B? How are you inspecting the ip? tcpdump?

Comment: I am inspecting the sip headers

Answer (score 0):

`172.24.0.1` is the ip address given to your host machine on the created network interface for `asterisk` network.

By default, for docker bridge network, if you go inside the container and run the `route` command, you can see that the default gateway will be `172.24.0.1` which corresponds to your host ip on the network interface. So what you are seeing in container B is the ip of the host, which the request from container A got routed to.

Comment: What do I set so traffic that leaves container A will be through its interface. So once arrived at container B souce ip is container A interface and not the host ip